# Is there a keyword for an empty object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null

I can do the following:

```
var obj = Object.create(null)
```

But the problem is I've grown to eschew the word null, coming from a sql server background.

I can do this:

```
var obj = Object.create({})
```

But that just looks like Object.create got smacked in the face with an ugly stick.

I can do this:

```
var empty = {}
var obj = Object.create(empty)
```

But that requires me defining another variable `empty`, which I'm looking to avoid.

Q: Is there a built-in variable in JavaScript that is defined as: {}?

Comment: `var obj = {};`

Comment: Why not just use the empty object literal? `var obj = {}`

Comment: The next line of code will be: obj.method = function() {...}

Comment: `var obj = new Object()`

Comment: @PhillipSenn than you can use typeof obj === 'object' after initializing by {}

Comment: Just because you don't like `null` because of the connotations it brings in SQL is no reason to avoid it in a language that it is an integral part of. `null` is an extremely valuable keyword/value. Best practices would say to initialize your variables to `null` upon declaration (when the initial value is not known yet) to explicitly differentiate undefined variables from declared, but uninitialized ones.

Comment: @PhillipSenn var obj = {}; obj.method = function(){}; is fine. Or create the whole object directly var obj = { method: function(){} }

Comment: You seem awful concerned about how the code "looks". Why not base your decisions on what the code *does*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a regular ol' JavaScript object, I would suggest this common construct:

```js
var object = {}

console.log(object) //=> {}
```

If you want a nicer shorthand for `Object.create(null)`, you can define a `Object.empty` function:

```js
Object.empty = function () {
  return Object.create(null)
}

var object = Object.empty()

console.log(object) //=> {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object) == null) //=> true
```